# Are there easy options for connecting Azure SQL Server VMs on a network?

Tags: sql-server, networking, azure, active-directory

I'm starting out on the road to be a DBA. I've completed a SQL Server course at my local community college, and I started diving into a good book, [Fundamentals of SQL Server 2012 Replication](http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/fundamentals-sql-server-2012-replication).

I'm at a chapter where the author says that I need to use SQL Server on three separate "machines," not *instances*, which can be connected to each other on a network, ideally with a domain controller/Active Directory. (I need to be able to connect to server A from server B, etc.)

> To make sure you get the most out of this and the following chapters, using three machines is indispensable. Because most enterprise networks are set up with a Windows domain, we'll assume that the three machines are part of a Windows domain. While it's possible to set up replication outside of a domain, it is not recommended. This book will therefore not go into any details on how that works. However, if you're forced to work outside of a domain, you must ensure that each user account used for replication exists on every machine and is configured with the same password, instead of existing just on the domain controller. (Page 79)

I have an Azure account, and I've been able to create three virtual machines without much effort. However, I'm not very knowledgeable about networks, so I'm running up against a wall on how I can get these machines to talk to each other. I assume that part of the problem is the particularities of Azure.

**Is there a reasonably simple way that I can do this, at least for training/testing purposes?**

FYI, this is what I have tried:

- Creating standard virtual machines on the default Azure network and connecting to them remotely. I'm unable to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) on one machine to locate any other machine.
- Creating a virtual network and some virtual machines that reside on them. I'm still unable to locate the other machines.
- Attempting to connect after starting the SQL Server Browser service, enabling named pipes, and creating an MSSQL endpoint.
- Using the Windows Server Manager to "Add other servers to manage." The other servers are not visible. The Active Directory tab says "The local computer is either not domain-joined, or it cannot access a domain controller."
- Pinging one machine's virtual network IP address from one of the other machines. The host was not found.
- Creating an Active Directory "forest" on Azure using [online documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine/). I stopped since I saw a lot of comments saying there were problems, and since I didn't really know what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the [tutorial for creating a SQL Server Always-On availability group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249504.aspx). It covers creating the VMs, joining them to a domain and registering them with a DNS all via a virtual network. Even if you're not actually creating the availability group, the tutorial will cover most of the topics you'd need to know with regards to sharing security and DNS resolution. :)

Comment: I'm running into an issue with this tutorial. It says that I should create a virtual network with an "affinity group," but the wizard doesn't provide that option to me. Can I ignore this, or do you think it is important? If important, do you have any idea how I can define one? (Let me know if this should be a new StackOverflow posting.)

Comment: We recently unveiled the ability to create a "regional vnet" that doesn't require an affinity group. So You can ignore that step.

Comment: I'm noticing a few more things in the tutorial that don't match what I'm actually seeing on the screen. What is the best way to provide feedback/corrections?

Comment: Posting on the MSDN forums is a good start. Additionally, many of the team check StackOverflow as well. Many of the docs are also opened sourced, so you can submit your own pull requests.

Comment: Cool. I'm running into another problem with the tutorial. I just posted a new StackOverflow question, ["How do I connect to an AD domain controller in Azure?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705809/how-do-i-connect-to-an-ad-domain-controller-in-azure)