# How do I connect to an AD domain controller in Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, active-directory

I'm working through an Azure tutorial on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249504.aspx) as suggested by @BrentDaCodeMonkey. Basically, I'm trying to learn how to set up a Windows domain, so I can use it for a some other SQL Server tutorials. See my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512101/are-there-easy-options-for-connecting-azure-sql-server-vms-on-a-network/25514031?noredirect=1#comment39902524_25514031).

I'm running into a problem where I cannot connect my servers to my Active Directory Name Controller. When I try to add my domain name to the server in System Properties, I get an error message instead of the Windows Security popup dialog.

> An Active Directory Name Controller (AD DC) for the domain "corp.ejm.com" could not be contacted. Ensure that the domain name is typed correctly. [...] The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Name Controller (AD NC) for domain "corp.ejm.com"; The error was: "This operation returned because the timeout period expired."

Note that I am able to verify the DC's IP address, with *nslookup* in the command prompt.

Complicating this issue is that the tutorial instructions don't exactly match what I'm seeing in Azure. For example, I'm not allowed to use Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 when setting up SQL Server virtual machines. I had to use Windows Server 2012 for those, but still used 2008 for the DC. I thought that the problem might be a conflicting operating systems, so I tried running the tutorial again using Windows Server 2012 for everything. Same error message.

Also note: the tutorial says that I should use the example domain, corp.contoso.com. I used my own example domain instead, corp.ejm.com. I'm wondering if this has something to do with it. My example domain is not registered on the Internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect to the DC VM and find out its IPAddress (10.*).

Go to the virtual network configuration and set the DNS server IP Address to that.

Also make sure you use this IP Address during step #8 in install SQL VMs section.

Now try joining the SQL VMs to the domain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked! Is it my imagination, or is the step to define the DNS server in the virtual network configuration page missing from the Azure tutorial?

Comment: Not Your imagination, documentation is not always full(